# Increase contrast of block-quote/code-block?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

There's a.. 3.9% colour difference between the background of code and the default answer background (245 vs 255) - could this be made a *little* easier to see?

For code it's not too big a problem, it stands out due to the syntax highlighting.. but block-quotes (someone elses words most likely) look very similar to the rest of the question, aside from a slight indentation..

Perhaps a subtle border would help?

*Edit:* The way SuperUser does this is great, could it be extended to the other sites?

Comment: This problem is even worse if the post has a background color (like green for accepted, red for deleted, etc).

Comment: Do whatever you want for quotes, but please please keep the code display clean - without any graphic "bar".

Answer (score 3):

I get quite different effects on the different screens I use - what looks OK on one is almost hidden on others.  I'm in favour of subtlety over shouting with the colours, but I support a slightly increased contrast.

Comment: Same experience here.