# Can we have Superuser blockquote formatting in Stackoverflow et al?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

On Super User, a post that uses the `blockquote` markup displays a graphic "bar" on the left edge of text. It is really useful when trying to display a quote within a quote. Can it be implemented on the other services (SO, SF, Meta)?

Super User Blockquote:

[image]

Stack Overflow Blockquote:

[image]

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/increase-contrast-of-block-quote-code-block

Comment: I don't quite think that is an accurate dupe call. rcar is specifically looking for the same design (maybe not color) on the other sites, not just an increase contrast on the blockquote box (which has been requested numerous times)

Comment: Read the edit on the linked question, TheTXI.

Comment: I hate you John Smithers

Comment: You really do, TheTXI? You're so cute :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the SU blockquote can be a tad jarring at first, I quickly grew to like it because it was the very first time that a blockquote was readily visible on every computer I use (sometimes it's too late while on others I can see them).

I would have no problem if it got emulated on all the other sites as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm strongly in favor of this, if only to see what sorts of things I can draw with it.

Comment: Like sands through the hourglass, so are the code blocks and blockquotes of our lives...